# How to filter out null values using an Angular pipe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I currently have an angular pipe which filters results based on the user's input. The only issue I am having is that some of the results do not have a value, therefore, I receive the following error:

> Cannot read property 'toLocaleLowerCase' of null

My pipe looks like this.

```
transform(value: QueuedTemplateDto[], filterBy: string): QueuedTemplateDto[] {
    filterBy = filterBy ? filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
    return filterBy 
        ? value.filter((check: QueuedTemplateDto) => check.user.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) 
        : value;
}
```

So I have tried to add an if statement which only allows the code to be executed is the check.user user attribute is not null however I receive an error every time I try to input this

My JavaScript knowledge is limited when it comes to this. Any help would much be appreciated!

Comment: This comment is not directly related to your question. It is discouraged to use pipes for filtering. See: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe . It would probably be best if you filter your data in your component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to check user property is defined or not(`null`), so add `check.user !== null` before your filter statement(for ignoring all falsy values simply use `check.user`).

```
transform(value: QueuedTemplateDto[], filterBy: string): QueuedTemplateDto[] {
filterBy = filterBy ? filterBy.toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
return filterBy ? value.filter((check: QueuedTemplateDto) =>
  check.user !== null && check.user.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) : value;}
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ----- here
```

**FYI :** You can change the condition as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the conditions in Javascript to reduce your code :

```
transform(value: QueuedTemplateDto[], filterBy: string): QueuedTemplateDto[] {
  return filterBy && 
    value.filter(item => item && 
      item.user && 
      item.user.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) 
    || value;
}
```

This is because of [**truthy/falsy**](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) values, also called the [*holy trinity of Javascript*](https://www.google.fr/search?q=js%20holy%20trinity&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjaiPTIid3cAhVKURoKHRWnDSMQsAR6BAgEEAE&biw=1920&bih=947).

See how it behaves :

```js
const empty = '';
const undef = undefined;
const nul = null;
const defined = 'This is defined';
const zero = 0;

const data = ['This is data'];

console.log(empty && data || 'it is empty');
console.log(undef && data || 'it is undefined');
console.log(nul && data || 'it is null');
console.log(nul && data || 'it is equal to zero');
console.log(defined && data || 'You will not see this message');
```

Comment: add `0` as well in your example :)

Comment: other possibilities are `NaN` and `false`

Comment: I've put links to avoid explaining everything in one post